# Unable to invite user to Azure Active Diretory

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Im trying to invite guest users to my AAD without success. I get the message "Unable to invite user" and when I check the error details I get the following

```
{"errorCode":"B2BError","localizedErrorDetails":null,"operationResults":null,"timeStampUtc":"2017-05-12T23:48:31.5694549Z","clientRequestId":"xxxxxxxxxxx","internalTransactionId":"xxxxxxxxxxx","upn":"xxxxxxxxxxx","tenantId":"xxxxxxxxxxx","userObjectId":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

I was able to invite users without problems a few weeks ago. But today Im receiving this error. I tried with a different tenant and it's working fine.

I also tried via powershell, using the [New-AzureADMSInvitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/Azuread/New-AzureADMSInvitation?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet from [Azure Active Directory V2 Preview Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.114). The same happens: one tenant works and the other doesnt. The error that I get on powershell is

```
New-AzureADMSInvitation : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSInvitation 
Code: Forbidden
Message: Generic authorization exception.
InnerError:
  RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxx
  DateTimeStamp: Fri, 12 May 2017 20:43:52 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:15
+ ... nvitation = New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress teste2@p ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADMSInvitation], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.NewAzureADMSInvitation
```

I even enabled the Premium trial to check if it had something to do with the free plan, but the problem persists

Does anybody know whats going on?

Comment: Is the account you invite the external users admin of the tenant? If not, please check whether the **Members can invite** feature is enable on the portal of Azure via Azure Active Directory->User settigns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message, maybe we should check your Azure AD configure settings, like the screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Also we can use **admin account of Azure AD** to invite user.